# Use global variable in Hotkey Block (Autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

My Autohotkey script doesn't work. Global Variables seem to have a null value in the "^1" block. How do I declare global variables that I can use in multiple hotkey blocks?

```
#if (true)
    global allActsRowY := 76
    global act1X := 249

    global allTownsY := 133
    global allTownsX := 245
    
    global clickDelay := 30
    
    
    ;Act 1 WP Town Shortcut
    ^1::
    {
        Click, left, %act1X%, %allActsRowY%
        Sleep, clickDelay
        Click, left, %allTownsX%, %allTownsY%
    }
    return
#if
```

Edit: The global variables were declared in the if-block. I made an edit to the code.

Comment: Variables have to be declared in the auto-execute section or within a hotkey/hotstring/or another function. Otherwise the script cannot initialize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume this isn't your whole script and you have e.g. hotkeys definitions, or something else, above all that. Which means that code execution never reaches those variable definitions.
You want to have the definitions in the script's [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).

Also worth noting that you're not defining the variables as global, you're defining them as [super-global](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#SuperGlobal), which is unnecessary and kind of bad practice.
You can just remove the word `global` from the definitions, variables already in the global scope if you define them outside of functions/classes. And hotkey blocks always have access to the global scope without any extra steps <sub><sup>(in AHKv1)</sup></sub>.

Comment: Didn't expect that but with the help of last answer figured it out myself. Never knew it was called auto-execute section. Thank you for mentioning the tipp about global. I introduced the keyword in my desperation to the problem.